# Calculating percentile for specific groups

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas, group-by

I have 3 columns. `Product Id`, `Price`, `Group` (values A, B, C, D)

I want to get price percentile for each group and I am running the following code.

```
for group, price in df.groupby(['group']):
    df['percentile'] = np.percentile(df['price'],60)
```

the column percentile has only one value 3.44 for each group.
The expected values for each group were `2.12, 3.43, 3.65, 4.76. 8.99`.

What is going wrong here, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use in loop not all `DataFrame` `df` with column `price`, but group `price` with column `price`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)))
df.columns = ['Product Id','group','price']
print df
   Product Id  group  price
0           5      8      9
1           5      0      0
2           1      7      6
3           9      2      4
4           5      2      4

for group, price in df.groupby(['group']):
    print np.percentile(df['price'],60)
4.8
4.8
4.8
4.8
group   

for group, price in df.groupby(['group']):
    print np.percentile(price['price'],60)
0.0
4.0
6.0
9.0
```

Another solution for [`np.percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) where is output `Serie`:

```
print df.groupby(['group'])['price'].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x,60))
group
0    0.0
2    4.0
7    6.0
8    9.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html):

```
print df.groupby(['group'])['price'].quantile(.6)
group
0    0.0
2    4.0
7    6.0
8    9.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

EDIT by comment:

If you need new column use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(20,3)))
>>> df.columns = ['Product Id','group','price']
>>> df
    Product Id  group  price
0            5      8      9
1            5      0      0
2            1      7      6
3            9      2      4
4            5      2      4
5            2      4      7
6            7      9      1
7            7      0      6
8            9      9      7
9            6      9      1
10           0      1      8
11           8      3      9
12           8      7      3
13           6      5      1
14           9      3      4
15           8      1      4
16           0      3      9
17           2      0      4
18           9      2      7
19           7      9      8
>>> df['percentil'] = df.groupby(['group'])['price'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(.6))
```

```
>>> df
    Product Id  group  price  percentil
0            5      8      9        9.0
1            5      0      0        4.4
2            1      7      6        4.8
3            9      2      4        4.6
4            5      2      4        4.6
5            2      4      7        7.0
6            7      9      1        5.8
7            7      0      6        4.4
8            9      9      7        5.8
9            6      9      1        5.8
10           0      1      8        6.4
11           8      3      9        9.0
12           8      7      3        4.8
13           6      5      1        1.0
14           9      3      4        9.0
15           8      1      4        6.4
16           0      3      9        9.0
17           2      0      4        4.4
18           9      2      7        4.6
19           7      9      8        5.8
```

Comment: Not sure if this meets my purpose. I do not need to print the output. I want to create a column "percentile" in the same dataframe df with 60th percentile for each group. This means my df will have now 4 columns, product id, price, group and percentile. In the next step I want create another column using this new "percentile" so that I can categorize Product Ids in each "group" by its "price". My next line is df['price_point'] = np.where(df['retailprice'] >= k,'high','low')

Answer (score 7):

You could try pandas [quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

```
df[['group', 'price']].groupby('group').quantile(.6)
```

**Return values at the given quantile over requested axis, a la numpy.percentile.**